# Excluding a file change in gulp but still keeping the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

The following is my simple gulp task:

- `gulp.src` is getting `script.js` as input
- minifies `script.js` and saves `script.min.js`
- removes `console.log` from ***both*** `script.js` and `script.min.js`
- updates `script.js` file and saves `script.min.js`

I want to simply remove `console.log` from a minified file (or `script.min.js`) not from `script.js`, and I am failing. I am looking for a way to run `.pipe(gulpRemoveLogging...` only on a minified file (i.e. `script.min.js`) and do not modify anything from `script.js`

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
minify = require("gulp-minify"),
gulpRemoveLogging = require("gulp-remove-logging");

var _dist_path = "./dist/"; // relative path

// minify JS files
gulp.task("minify-js", function() {
    return gulp.src(path.join(_dist_path, "/*.js"))
        .pipe(minify({
            ext: {
                src: ".js",
                min: ".min.js"
            },
            ignoreFiles: ["-min.js"]
        }))
        .pipe(gulpRemoveLogging({
            namespace: ["console", "window.console"]    // remove these namespaces. e.g. console.log("..."), window.console.log("...")
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(_dist_path));
});
```

Comment: If you delete the dist folder before running the command does it work for you? The code you provided should work based on the [documentation for gulp-remove-logging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-remove-logging).  You could also try to enable verbose logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem:

Added `.pipe(gulpIgnore("smartsitescripts.js"))` between `.pipe(minify({ ...` and `.pipe(gulpRemoveLogging ...`

```
var gulpIgnore = require("gulp-ignore");

...
    .pipe(minify({
        ext: {
            src: ".js",
            min: ".min.js"
        },
        ignoreFiles: ["-min.js"]
    }))
    .pipe(gulpIgnore("script.js"))  // <---- this line solved the problem
    .pipe(gulpRemoveLogging({
        namespace: ["console", "window.console"]    // remove these namespaces. e.g. console.log("..."), window.console.log("...")
    }))
...
```

That line of code will exclude `script.js` from stream hence stream will contain only `script.min.js`.